# How do I output a SAS data set looking exactly like my result in PROC TABULATE?

Tags: sas, proc, ods

So I am a complete beginner in SAS and it seems that I am missing something that is very obvious since I cannot figure this out. Hopefully someone could help me on this.

I have disorganized data in a .csv file with which I need to compute some stuff for, but the first step before any of that is to organize my data into a workable data set in SAS. So first, I run a `DATA` step to import my .csv file. Then, I run a `PROC TABULATE` to make it look exactly how I want it to so that I can compute additional variables as follows:

`PROC TABULATE DATA = Work.Temp OUT = Work.Final;`

However, the outputted data set Work.Final looks completely different from what I was able to create in `PROC TABULATE`. Basically, I was able to get the data into the form I want using `PROC TABULATE`, and I want my outputted SAS data set to look exactly in this form. Instead, the data set Work.Final is again a disorganized mess.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing your code we cannot suggest solutions. However, based on experience it's unlikely you'll be able to use proc tabulate. Most likely it will be a transpose. But those are guesses.

Comment: I agree with @Reeza, `proc tabulate` only changes the aesthetics of the dataset that is the way you would want to see it in the output. If you want to change the structure of the dataset as it is stored `proc transpose` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, PROC TRANSPOSE was indeed the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ODS output to write a CSV file from your Proc tabulate.

```
ODS CSV FILE=”C:\Final.CSV”;

PROC Tabulate data=work.temp;
    class bla bla bla;
    table etc etc;
RUN;

ODS CSV CLOSE;
```